# A line break in the array declaration

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an expression like this:

```
psi = [5 + 1/60, 7 + 20/60, 14 + 33/60, .... ]; %  25 elements in here
```

Writing this declaration in one line takes a lot of place, because the expression is too wide. I can't move the part on the next line since the structure of array breaks and a vector turns into a matrix.

I have to break the expression into several pieces. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Did you check [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html) from Matlab?
It may be what you want!

In order to continue a statement to the next line you can use ellipsis (...).
An ellipsis outside a quoted text is equivalent to a space. For example,

```
x = [1.23...
4.56];
```

is the same as

```
x = [1.23 4.56];
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You are right, thanks for mention it! However, mathworks is a valid and well-known documentation for Matlab. That is why I didn't think to put more.